# Get results from all languages in wp-job-manager search with WPML active

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a website with WPML active and I'm using wp-job-manager plugin to list job openings. There are 10+ languages and 5 regions.

Right now, when I search for jobs, it shows jobs posted only in user selected language.

I want search results to show each every job posted in that region, no matter added in which language.

**Updates till now**

I have managed all jobs to appear in 'All region' by following Code:

```
function wpml_custom_search( $query ) {
    $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] = true;
    return $query;
}
```

but when user selects any region like 'north america' , or 'asia'.. this function do not work. I'm using **wp job manager location** add-on.

What am I missing?

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem? if so, can you please explain how you did it, thank you.